# Using parentheses in strings of text make xpath fail

Tags: xpath, selenium

My question is this: is it possible to write an xpath in which parentheses are interpreted as part of a string?

My selenium script keeps failing as soon as I use parentheses in a `contains` function.

For example:

```
//li/div/span[contains(text(),"Komkommer (BONUS)")]
```

Comment: Works for me on Java WebDriver, Selenium 2.21.0, IE8, Win XP SP3. Could you post the whole Selenium code?

Comment: verifyElementPresent
//li[@id="not-in-order-header"]/preceding-sibling::li/div/span[contains(text(),"${item1}")]

I get the "item1" from a storeText i used earlier:

storeText
//div/a[@class="more"]/following-sibling::span
item1

So weird, it works for me as long as i exclude the (Bonus)

Comment: Any compliant XPath engine evaluates the provided XPath expression without raising errors.

Comment: I guess i'll start looking in another direction.... thanks for the assistance anyway, i was convinced it had something to do with the parentheses :(

Comment: Aren't the parantheses stored in some funny way (e.g. `&#40;` and `&#41;`)?

Comment: Does You tried to select them from browser console ???

Comment: Actually parenthesis work perfectly fine in Selenium. I used them in Selenium 3.4.0, Chrome:59.0.3071.115, Win10

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It has to do with encoding. Your parenthesis string may have different encoding than the comparison base.